# Javascript | Callback to clearInterval, possible?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

In this code snippet i make a http call every 6 seconds to see if some data has arrived on the sever. (I could not use websockets or Server-sent events so i had to do it this way).

The thing is that when `data!= '-1'`  and `myaddress == data.address` sometimes i get two popup windows instead of one. I don't know what can be wrong in this code but it is happening....

```
var id; 

id = setInterval(function() {
    $.get( 'https://example.com?dir='+myaddress,{}, function(data) { 
        if (data != '-1') {
            if (myaddress == data.address) {
                clearInterval(id); 

                //(..whatever..)

                popitup(); // show's a new pop up window
            } 
        return; 
        } 
    });
}, 6 * 1000);
```

Comment: may be it is popping out from the second request?

Comment: Sure. Happens whenever your request that signals success takes longer than 6 seconds.

Comment: How long does the request take to respond? Maybe two requests are queuing, so both pop ups are from both responses?

Comment: @Bergi you are right, how could this be solved?

Comment: @Egidi: I'd recommend to replace the `setInterval` with a pseudo-recursive `setTimeout`, so that you can make it 6 seconds *between* requests (not from request start to request start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX request is being made before the interval is cleared, so it's queued, and both end up being executed. You can add a check to see if the interval has been cleared with a bit of extra code:

```
var id; 

id = setInterval(function() {
    $.get( 'https://example.com?dir='+myaddress,{}, function(data) { 
        if (data != '-1') {
            if (myaddress == data.address && id) { // make sure id isn't undefined
                id = clearInterval(id); // reset id to undefined

                //(..whatever..)

                popitup(); // show's a new pop up window
            } 
        return; 
        } 
    });
}, 6 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

because the ajax request MAY be slow sometimes but the interval of your timer works each 6 seconds ALL the time. fix it like that:

```
var id, ajax; 

id = setInterval(function() 
{
    if (ajax) return;

    $.get( 'https://example.com?dir='+myaddress,{}, function(data) 
    { 
        if (data != '-1') 
        {
            if (myaddress == data.address) 
            {
                clearInterval(id); 

                //(..whatever..)

                popitup(); // show's a new pop up window
            } 

            return; 
        } 

        ajax = false;
    });

    ajax = true;

}, 6 * 1000);
```